# How can I use the coordinates of my player and the coordinates of any block in an array to detect collision?

Tags: pygame, collision-detection, python-3.4

I have array of Lists:

```
blocks0 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1]
blocks1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks3 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks4 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]                   
blocks5 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks6 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks7 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks8 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks9 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks10= [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks11= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1]

blockList = [blocks0, blocks1, blocks2, blocks3, blocks4, blocks5, blocks6, blocks7, blocks8, blocks9, blocks10, blocks11]
```

A 1 signifies a block.
A 0 signifies an open space.
Each digit is a 50x50 pixel block/space.
Using blockList[y][x] I can find each number seperately.

y signifies which list in the group of lists.
x signifies which number in the list y.

However I did not use x and y in my code for this.

I have a character who is 50x50 pixels and moves 10 pixels every loop if i use the arrow keys.

How can I detect collision between my player and a number 1?

I have tried:

```
lefX = x
rigX = x + player_width
topY = y
botY = y + player_height

lefX -= int(lefX % 50)
rigX -= int(rigX % 50)
topY -= int(topY % 50)
botY -= int(botY % 50)

lefX = int(lefX/50)
rigX = int(rigX/50)
topY = int(topY/50)
botY = int(botY/50)

if blockList[topY][lefX] == 1:     ##This is just for going left.
    if not((blockList[topY][lefX]*50)+50 >= x):
        x += x_changeLeft
else:
    x += x_changeLeft
```

I did try some other ways but I got rid of them when they didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.
Any questions will be answered as soon as possible.

Thanks

Comment: While I'm not sure how to answer this question, in an actual pygame window you can use pygame Groups to detect collisions. Check out this link for details on the methods you can use to detect collisions between groups of sprites. 
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

Comment: I had a look at that, however, i did not see how i could incorporate that into my code. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I have changed the block size to 20, but you can easily adjust it back.) Use z/x/p/l to move the player.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

blocks0 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1]
blocks1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks3 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks4 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]                   
blocks5 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks6 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks7 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks8 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks9 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks10= [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1]
blocks11= [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1]

blockList = [blocks0, blocks1, blocks2, blocks3, blocks4, blocks5, blocks6, blocks7, blocks8, blocks9, blocks10, blocks11]

class player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.row = 3
        self.col = 4
        self.leftcount = 0
        self.rightcount = 0
        self.upcount = 0
        self.downcount = 0

pygame.init()
size = width, height = 510, 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((0,0,0))

def init():
    global theplayer, clock
    theplayer = player()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

def run():

    global theplayer

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_z]:
            theplayer.leftcount+=1
            if theplayer.leftcount == 5:
                theplayer.leftcount = 0
                if theplayer.col>0:
                    theplayer.col -=1
                    if blockList[theplayer.row][theplayer.col] == 1:
                        print "hit"

        if keys[K_x]:
            theplayer.rightcount+=1
            if theplayer.rightcount == 5:
                theplayer.rightcount = 0
                if theplayer.col<15:
                    theplayer.col +=1
                    if blockList[theplayer.row][theplayer.col] == 1:
                        print "hit"

        if keys[K_p]:
            theplayer.upcount+=1
            if theplayer.upcount == 5:
                theplayer.upcount = 0
                if theplayer.row>0:
                    theplayer.row -=1
                    if blockList[theplayer.row][theplayer.col] == 1:
                        print "hit"

        if keys[K_l]:
            theplayer.downcount+=1
            if theplayer.downcount == 5:
                theplayer.downcount = 0
                if theplayer.row <11:
                    theplayer.row +=1
                    if blockList[theplayer.row][theplayer.col] == 1:
                        print "hit"

        clock.tick(30)  
        update()

def update():

        background.fill((0,0,0))
        size = 20

        for row in range(12):
            for col in range(16):
                if blockList[row][col] == 1:
                    pygame.draw.rect(background, (255,255,255), (size*col, size*row, size, size))

        pygame.draw.rect(background, (255,255,255), (theplayer.col*size, theplayer.row*size, size, size))
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    run()
```